# Apply a boolean to falling particles?

Tags: particles

I have a particle emitter working just fine. I want to make the falling particles vanish in one area as they fall. I tried applying a boolean, but the particles appear to ignore it.

Is this even possible? If so how?

I don't want the emitter impacted, only the falling particles. I have the boolean operation after the emitter in the modifier stack and the use modifier stack turned on. It appears that I can boolean the emitter itself but not the particles.

[image: boolean]
[image: settings]

The square in the image is really a cube object that passes all the way through the emitted zone. So when working, I should end up with the particles falling but vanishing within that square area and reappearing after.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could define the cube as Holdout:

```
Note: might be some sideeffects:
```

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/holdout.html

[image]

with holdout:

[image]

without holdout:

[image]

Comment: Oh man, that just left a big black box in the middle of my scene. It looked in the viewport but doesn't render correctly at all.